# auth0 nodejs login username password fails

Tags: r, node.js, nginx, shiny, auth0

I'm trying to build a login page for my Shiny application, using the auth0 services, nginx, node.js and the git repo github.com:auth0/shiny-auth0.git.
You can find the full tutorial [here](https://auth0.com/blog/adding-authentication-to-shiny-server/)

Everything works fine, except for the fact that I can't login using a valid username/password combination (made within the auth0 webpage). It is possible though to login using for example your Google account (it's redirected to Shiny application, as expected).

The generic error message I get is stating `WE COULD NOT REACH THE SERVER. PLEASE CHECK YOUR CONNECTION AND TRY AGAIN.`

I can't find any working solutions in the documentation, or on the forum of Auth0. Did anyone experience similar problems, using Auth0, possibly in combination with Ubuntu 16.04, Node.js, R Shiny and Nginx and found a solution?

Help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick lies in the `Allowed Callback URLs` and the `Allowed Origins (CORS)`. Both fields need to be filled in properly within the Auth0 Client setup. This means that the allowed callback URL needs to be equal to your domain of the Shiny app, starting with the proper protocol (in this case `http`) and ending with `/callback`. The same URL should be used in the `.env` file. In my case, this was something like `http://ec2-123-456-789.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com/callback`.

Then don't forget to also use the `Allowed Origins (CORS)`, since the origin is not exactly equal to the callback. The origin uses `https` protocol, instead of `http`. Hence use something like `https://ec2-123-456-789.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com` for your Origin.

Comment: did you have to do anything else to get the even most basic redirect working (even when logging in using gmail). I also have been following the tutorial and cannot get the redirect and callback to work. It always brings me to an nginx page not found.  Any advice is much appreciated.